# Replace in shell \n by \\n

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm looking how can I convert a string like that :

```
foo\nbar
```

into :

```
foo\\nbar
```

What I have seen so far is that `tr` can't do that because it's working only on chars, and I couldn't find any other solution working...

Exemple :

```
redgl0w@anarchy ~> cat test
foo
bar
```

And I'm looking to get :

```
redgl0w@anarchy ~> echo test
foo\nbar
```

Comment: Is the string in a file? In a variable?

Comment: It is in a variable

Comment: Your `cat test` command tells us it's actually two lines in a file...

Comment: Yep, and I want to replace the line feed by \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/' file
```

If your string is in a variable, use:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/' <<<"$variable"
```

Or

```
printf '%s' "$variable" | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/'
```

If you want, you can save it as a variable:

```
$ cat test
foo
bar
$ test=$(perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g' test)
$ echo "$test"
foo\nbar\n
```

Or, if you don't want to convert the final, trailing newline, and assuming your file is small enough to fit in RAM, you can do:

```
$ test=$(perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/\\n/g; s/\\n$/\n/' test); 
$ echo "$test"
foo\nbar
```

Or, a better way suggested by [Rakesh Sharma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/416159/rakesh-sharma) in the comments which doesn't require holding the file in memory:

```
$ perl -lpe '$\ = eof ? qq(\n) : q(\n);s/\n/\\n/;' test
foo\nbar
```

Comment: Whether the file is big or small, the canonical way is to assign the `ORS` : `perl -lpe '$\ = eof ? qq(\n) : q(\n)' `

Comment: Your `perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g' ` adds a trailing `\\n`  not to mention that the `/g` modifier is redundant since the file is read line by line without chomping, so there's just one newline in a record. `perl -pe 'eof || s/\n/\\n/'`

Comment: The slurpy solution can be rewritten as: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?!\z)/\\n/g'`

Comment: Thanks, @RakeshSharma, good points all.

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```bsh
$ cat test
foo
bar
baz

$ content=$(<test)

$ joined=${content//$'\n'/\\n}

$ echo "$joined"
foo\nbar\nbaz
```

Comment: Ooh, of course! The default behavior of command substitution is to strip the trailing newline. This is a better approach than mine.